# Pyspark Mutlipe Dataframe initializations

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

Hey so this may be a noob question, I am trying to work with a file that has 1 million rows and I am trying to find a similarity to a corpus of documents and I read it into a spark dataframe called test

```
df_spk = read_s3_to_spkdf(schema, 's3://Test/{}/dump.csv001'.format(timestamp)),
```

Now I perform multiple operations each time saving it to a new dataframe

I create an udf which returns the similarity score for the original to the new documents

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("max_sim_origin", StringType(), False),
    StructField("max_sim", FloatType(), False)])func_udf = udf(lambda x: func_dict(x),schema)
```

Once this is done I store it into another dataframe and keep doing multiple transformations and storing the result onto a new dataframe each time

```
df_new_2=df_spk.select("Orig_doc_id", func_udf(col("text")).alias('Output'))
df_new_3=df_new_2.select("Orig_doc_id","Output.*")
df_new_4=df_new_3.filter(df_new_3.max_sim>=0.5)
df_new_5=df_new_4.join(df_spk_train,df_new_4.max_sim_origin ==  df_spk_train.text,"inner")
df_new_5.write.mode('overwrite').csv("s3://Test/Test_output")
```

When I run df_new_2 individually, it runs fine and with a smaller dataset all the below functions run fine as well and write it into my s3 folder, When I run it with my complete dataset, the job fails with

```
Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 51.2 GB of 51.1 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
```

Since my datasize is only 1.6GB and I am running a 6 node c4.8xlarge is this happening because each of these new dataframes are getting created and stored seperately. I come from a python background and when df_spk executes, the results are stored into df_new_2 but I know in spark that these are just transformation statements and only get executed when we execute something like df_new_1.show(). I also notice that let say df_new_2 takes 3 hours to execute After I do df_new_2.show() and execute df_new_3.show(). It again takes 3 hours to execute and the rest of the actions are compounded after that.

Would it make more sense for me to do this

```
df_spk=df_spk.select("Orig_doc_id", func_udf(col("text")).alias('Output'))
df_spk=df_spk.select("Orig_doc_id","Output.*")
df_spk=df_spk.filter(df_new_3.max_sim>=0.5)
df_spk=df_spk.join(df_spk_train,df_spk.max_sim_origin ==  df_spk_train.text,"inner")
df_spk.write.mode('overwrite').csv("s3://Test/Test_output")
```

Pyspark newbie here so excuse me if it is really a dumb question

Comment: is there any way you can get rid of UDF and use PySpark functions instead?

Comment: You also have to make sure the slowness is not caused by data skewing. You can figure that out by looking at Spark UI, seeing let's say you have 1000 tasks, 999 of them finish in 1 min and the last one running for hours.

Comment: last one, the later changes you made (overriding `df_spk`) wouldn't change a thing. As you said yourself, the transformation is lazy, and since you don't cache anything, reusing dataframe variable won't help

Comment: I cannot convert the UDF to Pyspark because of complexity. Is there a solution for data skewing?